# Get a value from an associative array with $_GET

Tags: php, arrays, variables, url, get

Say for example that I have this variable

```
$p0001 = array("title"=>"This is the title","name"=>"Just Me");
```

And the URL is

```
https://www.example.com?id=p0001
```

How do I get the correct array from PHP? I've tried

```
echo $_GET["id"]["title"];
```

To explain little more, say I have two array variables. I want it to echo the "title" from from the array `$p0001`. So how do I make sure I gets the variable I put in `$_GET`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

So, your variable name is `$p0001`. Your GET parameter `id` is basically a pointer to the variable name, so using variable variables, we can reference the variable we're looking for:

```
$varname = $_GET['id']; // $varname = 'p0001';
$$varname; // this is basically $p0001
$$varname['title']; // and you can get your title from $p0001
```

You could also check if a variable exists before using with `isset($$varname)`